# How to expose gRPC health check in headless .NET worker service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, .net-8.0, health-check

I'm running a headless (i.e. no HTTP endpoints) .NET 8 worker service on k8s. I'd like to expose gRPC health checks which k8s can use for readiness/liveness probes. However, the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-up-grpc-health-checks) only seem to cater for ASP.NET Core apps which do (also) provide HTTP endpoints:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddGrpcHealthChecks()
                .AddCheck("Sample", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy());

var app = builder.Build();  // <-- this does not exist in the worker service

app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
app.MapGrpcHealthChecksService();
```

The worker service obviously doesn't provide the `WebApplicationBuilder` but instead only a `HostApplicationBuilder`:

```
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
```

Any pointers how to expose this with minimum overhead are much appreciated!

Comment: I would argue that just making it "headful" would be the easiest approach. Just convert it to "ordinary" ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: ^^ Probably easier than something like having a _second_ 'headful' service that does nothing else but translate and proxy from an HTTP Health-Endpoint to a (local) gRPC EP in the Headless Service ...

Comment: I understand your argument about it being the easiest approach. But a) is it the one with the least overhead? And b) the service already exists and is working. So changing it to a headful service would be quite some work

Comment: @silent _"a) is it the one with the least overhead?"_ - if you want to utilize the standard functionality - then yes (also how much overhead do you expect?) _"So changing it to a headful service would be quite some work"_ - I would not expect that many TBH. But without seeing actual setup it is hard to tell.

Comment: `Grpc.AspNetCore.HealthChecks` is based on `Grpc.HealthCheck`. Have you had a look at [its source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/src/Grpc.HealthCheck) yet?

Comment: Also have a look at what [`AddGrpcHealthChecks()` etc. does](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/933023b6f818ec54dfe84e7d31ec50dfe5044c13/src/Grpc.AspNetCore.HealthChecks/GrpcHealthChecksServiceExtensions.cs#L64). Maybe it's easy to do the something similar with your builder.